# Downloads folder keeps coming back after I delete it

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, cinnamon, fedora-22, xdg

My downloads folder keeps coming back after I delete it. I want to have my home directory setup so that it looks like the following:

```
desktop documents loads
```

Per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/211572/2098) I have changed my `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to look like this:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/loads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

However the folder named `Downloads` keeps appearing in my home directory. I have changed the download location in Google Chrome, etc. but that has not helped. How can I delete this for good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chrome :
[Issue 4575: Documents\Downloads folder is created even when the download location is different](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4575).

This bug report dates back to 2008, was briefly fixed around the end of 2008,
but was reported as being back on September 2009.

The bug report itself was closed on December 2008, and this comment was added on
October 11, 2012 :

> This issue has been closed for some time. No one will pay attention to
>   new comments. If you are seeing this bug or have new data, please
>   click New Issue to start a new bug.

You could start a new bug report issue, and hope that some ambitious developer
will take on this seven years old bug.

Question: Does this folder come back even after you have
cleared out the downloaded files list?

Comment: I have not tried clearing out the downloaded file list. I will do that and report back. As for now I've resorted to deleting the pesky folder in my morning script.

Comment: I've cleared my downloads list and I have yet to see the folder again. However more time will be needed to see if it comes back. I also submitted a new bug report for anyone who cares: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583125

Comment: The downloads folder did not come back after clearing the download list. I'll continue to work with the Google guys and see if they can reproduce it. I gave you the bounty since you found the root cause of the issue.